# Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-angular'

Tags: eslint

I'm trying to integrate ESLint into my project and I'm running into the error: *"Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-angular'"* when I run `$ eslint *.js`.

The only way I can get this to run is by installing eslint-plugin-angular globally, but that seems wrong (unless I'm missing something??).

I'm running:

- node v0.12.7
- npm 3.3.4
- eslint v1.5.0
- eslint-plugin-angular 0.12.0

ESLint is installed globally.

My `package.json` file has the following entries:

- "eslint": "^1.5.0",
- "eslint-plugin-angular": "^0.12.0",

I have `$ rm -rf node_modules` and rerun `$ npm install` to make sure there wasn't some kind of npm dependency issue or corruption. I also verified the directory permissions in `node_modules` to make sure access is possible.

My `.eslintrc` contains:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "angular"
    ],
    "rules": {
    "angular/ng_controller_name": [
        2,
        "/[A-Z].*Controller$/"
    ],
    "quotes": [
        2,
        "single"
    ]
    },
        "globals": {
        "angular": true
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Thx!
ps. I did open a ticket on github: https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/issues/222 -- just wondering if someone in the Stack community has run into this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-plugins

"Note: A globally-installed instance of ESLint can only use globally-installed ESLint plugins. A locally-installed ESLint can make sure of both locally- and globally- installed ESLint plugins."

This falls under read the fine print in the documentation. :/

There are two ways to deal with this:

(1) Install the plugin(s) globally. I'm not a particular fan of this because I have multiple client projects that are on different versions of dependencies and I can't necessarily just bump them all to the same version.

(2) Install the plugin(s) locally and add a script to your `package.json` file:

```
{
    ... other stuff
    "scripts": {
        "eslint": "eslint",
        "lint": "eslint. "
    }
    ... other stuff
}
```

(If you're completely new to this, just keep in mind that `... other stuff` isn't what you'd actually want in your package.json file...)

With this setup, I'm able to use `npm run eslint` to use `eslint` and I use `npm run lint` to actually lint my project.

You can find documentation on the `scripts` field for the `package.json` file here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: i.e. install `eslint-plugin-angular` globally

Comment: When providing examples, I like to use a comment for any line like ` ... other stuff`

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty much guaranteed to run into this problem if you follow a guide that tells you to use `npm install -g eslint`, which is the recommended way to install ESLint, and then proceeds to immediately tell you to use `eslint --init` to create a configuration for your project. The issue is that `eslint --init` *will* install the packages you need, but it will install them *locally*, even if it is being run from a globally installed `eslint`. I was none the wiser until I tried editing a file in Emacs and `flycheck` reported an error from ESLint:

```
Error: Failed to load plugin react: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
[...]
```

I like to allow both a global installation and a local one. I might use the global one for experimental code that I still want to be checked but does not belong to any specific project, and local installations with more specific needs. So I created a script stored as `~/bin/eslint`. Since `~/bin` is early on my `PATH`, this script is used in place of any globally install `eslint`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Find the top of the code hierarchy, and move there.
prefix=`npm prefix`
[ -n $prefix ] && cd $prefix

# Execute the local eslint if it exists.    
local_eslint=./node_modules/.bin/eslint
[ -x $local_eslint ] && exec $local_eslint "$@"

# If not, execute the global one.
exec /path/to/global/eslint "$@"
```

(For those who don't know, `exec` is final. If the first `exec` is executed then nothing after it will execute.)

This script assumes an project structure suitable for `npm` (i.e. there's a `package.json` that `npm prefix` can find). It would have to be adapted to other situations.

My global `eslint` is in an unusual location, adapt the script to point it to where you have it installed.