# How can I get ESLint to lint HTML files in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, lint

I have a Javascript browser project split over multiple files and can't get ESLint to lint the script tags of my HTML file under the same global scope so that declarations and calls of classes and functions in one file are recognised in another.

Here is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

This is the contents of foo.js:

```
sayHello();
```

and bar.js:

```
function sayHello() {
  console.log('Hello');
}
```

And I have linked them both in the HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="libraries/bar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I thought that the solution to this was to use the eslint-plugin-html package but have tried to configure it with no luck. These are the packages I've installed locally to the project:

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:Demo alexmcdermott$ npm list --depth=0
demo@1.0.0 /Users/alexmcdermott/GitHub/Demo
├── eslint@5.12.0
├── eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.1.0
├── eslint-plugin-html@5.0.0
└── eslint-plugin-import@2.14.0
```

I'm using the VSCode editor but have also had the same problem in the terminal:

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:Demo alexmcdermott$ npx eslint --ext .js,.html .

/Users/alexmcdermott/GitHub/Demo/foo.js
  1:1  error  'sayHello' is not defined  no-undef

/Users/alexmcdermott/GitHub/Demo/libraries/bar.js
  1:10  error    'sayHello' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  2:3   warning  Unexpected console statement          no-console

✖ 3 problems (2 errors, 1 warning)
```

and the same in VSCode:

[image: vscode error]

This is my ESLint config:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "airbnb-base",
    "plugins": [ "html" ]
}
```

and I've also configured VSCode to run ESLint on HTML files with these options in my VSCode user settings:

```
{
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
    "eslint.options": {
        "extensions": [ ".js", ".html" ]
    },
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript",
        {
            "language": "html",
            "autoFix": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Although I must be doing something wrong, or am missing the point of the eslint-plugin-html? If anyone has any input as to what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this I'd greatly appreciate it as I've been stuck on this for ages. Please let me know if I need to provide more info, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 17):

I have this in `<projectfolder>/.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
  "eslint.validate": [ "javascript", "html" ]
}
```

I'm using an `.eslintrc.js` that looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "eslint-plugin-html",
  ],
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
  }
};
```

I have lots of rules defined but didn't paste them above

Result:

[image]

Comment: added my `.eslintrc.js`. I'm pretty sure the plugins section can be just "html". You installed it though right? `npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-html`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I believe I have that as well if you look at the last two pictures. I just specified my validations in the user settings not the workplace settings for VSCode. Although I just tried your way as well but it didn't work. I know it is referencing my config file because it makes other syntactical changes on a per file basis such as replacing semicolons but it just doesn't work across Javascript files.

Comment: Yea I have it installed. I've put a copy of my npm list output in the question so you can see the installed packages and their versions

Comment: This is all I get in the ESLint output tab when I restart: 

[Info  - 10:51:04 AM] ESLint server stopped.
[Info  - 10:51:04 AM] ESLint server running in node v8.9.3
[Info  - 10:51:04 AM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 10:51:06 AM] ESLint library loaded from: /Users/alexmcdermott/GitHub/Demo/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js

Comment: added a screenshot of how I tested. Just made a test.html, a script tag, and typed some JS.

Comment: Ah ok I see. I just tired making an inline script tag like in your image and it worked.  So that shows that the plugin is working, but I would like to get it working with linked Javascript files so that I can keep my code in seperate files rather than all in one HTML file.

Comment: it doesn't look at links. It looks at .js and .html files in your project

Comment: @Alex I'm trying to lint my Javascript which is split into seperate files and linked into my HTML file (It's a web app). So I have a function in one file and that function is called in another file but ESLint cannot see that it's defined and then also used because its split over two files.

Comment: I thought that was the whole point of the eslint-plugin-html? This is from their npm page: "When linting a HTML with multiple script tags, this plugin tries to emulate the browser behavior by sharing the global scope between scripts by default"

Comment: AFAIK that's normal. Either you define it using `import foo from 'foo.js';` or you define it with a comment `/* global foo */`. Eslint doesn't look across files and really can't

Comment: So instead of linking all the js files in the HTML file I link one main javascript file and then use "import foo from 'foo.js';" inside of that to include all my modules? Is import a part of browser javascript or will I need to compile it first? Or just have a inline script in the HTML with the import foo from ...   ?

Comment: No, if `bar.js` uses stuff in `foo.js` called `fooFunction` then in `bar.js` you'd put `/* global fooFunction */` to tell eslint that some global function called `fooFunction` is defined outside of `bar.js`.  [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) is ES7 which is the newer way to import definitions from other modules. If you're using `import` then you *generally* don't need the global comments. If you're not using import you do need them in every file that uses something not defined in that file.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on github for the plugin. I suspect it won't do what you want. It might not require a global comment in an inline script for a script included on that page. It seems unlikely it would not require globals to be defined when used inside .js file since the plugin is only for html.

Comment: Ah ok I see. Yea it think I'll give the ES7 imports a try because it seems like a bit of a hassle having to define globals for every file. And yea I might check with the plugins Github but I feel like the problem was just me misunderstanding its purpose.  Thanks very much for the help and info :)

Answer (score 12):

Use [`eslint-plugin-html`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-html):

1. Run `npm install eslint-plugin-html --save-dev` in your Terminal.
2. Open `.eslintrc.js` and add there `plugins: ["html"]` right after `module.exports`. If you have `.json` or different format than the `.js` then just follow the pattern and add the same values on the same nesting level.
3. Run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .html .` in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

- Open `.html` file
- Open OUTPUT panel
- Select ESLint channel
- See errors and fix them

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just tried you're suggestion and don't have any errors in the ESLint out panel on my HTML document

Comment: Then idk. Could be duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683223/cannot-find-module-eslint-plugin-angular

Comment: I don't believe it's a duplicate. I don't get an error like that. If I uninstall the eslint-plugin-html extension I get that error but it disappears once I reinstall it. So it seems like ESLint can see the plugin but it isn't working for some reason?

Answer (score -1):

Try using htmlhint.  It lints html files fairly well.  https://htmlhint.com/